# Why does ScrollView randomly push my views content downwards?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-scrollview

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TrendingView : View {
    
    @State var selectedTab: Tabs = .hot
    @State private var searchText = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        NavigationView {
            
            VStack {
                
                
                HStack {
                    
                    Text(" Trending")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .frame(width: 175, height: 50, alignment: .leading)
                        .overlay(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                                .stroke(.black, lineWidth: 2)
                        )
                        .italic()
                        .fontWeight(.heavy)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(hue: 1.0, saturation: 0.977, brightness: 0.985))
                    
                        .offset(x: -75, y: -25)
                        .padding(.bottom, -20)
                    
                    
                    NavigationLink(destination: testT()) {
                        Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass.circle.fill")
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .padding(.bottom, -20)
                        
                        
                        
                    }
                    .offset(x: 50, y: -25)
                    .padding(.leading, 5.0)
                    

                }
                ScrollView {
                    VStack {
                        Text("Hot Items ")
                        
                            .bold()
                            .italic()
                            .offset(x: 5)
                        
                            .frame(width: 120, height: 25, alignment: .leading)
                            .overlay(
                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                                    .stroke(.black, lineWidth: 2)
                            )
                            .background(.yellow)
                            .offset(x: -130, y: 5)
                        
                        
                        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                            HStack {
                                NavigationLink(destination: ImageTest()) {
                                    Image("testpic1")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                                }
                                NavigationLink(destination: ImageTest()) {
                                    Image("testpic3")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                                }

            }.offset(y: 30)
            
            
        }
    }
}
```

There seems to be some error with scrollview above my vstack as it randomly causes all the content on this view to shift downwards when switching to and from other views.Ive tried removing the scrollview and the error disappears and also tried changing it around in other places but I still get the error Can anybody point me in the right direction? Thanks

Comment: To make it easier to answer your question, please create a [mcve]. Your code as supplied does not compile

Comment: Fixed, added: .navigationBarTitle(Text(""), displayMode: .inline)
                .navigationBarHidden(true) to the bottom of my code

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, added to the bottom of my code and it seems like the issue is solved

```
.navigationBarTitle(Text(""), displayMode: .inline)
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
```